# Comparing the 2 Array Triplets in C Language using a function

Tags: c, arrays

I'm comparing arrays here by elements value then storing the score in `score[]` array
I would like to know how to print all the score array using  score = compareTriplets(a,b) if possible.
If not, what is the best approach to get the output?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a[3];
int b[3];

int score[] = {0,0};

int *compareTriplets(int a[], int b[]);

int *compareTriplets(int a[], int b[])
{
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if( a[i] > b[i])
        {
            score[0] += 1;
        }
        else if( b[i] > a[i])
        {
            score[1] += 1;
        }
    }

    return score;
}


int main()
{
   
    int k;
    int score;
    
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a[0], &a[1], &a[2]);

    scanf("%d %d %d", &b[0], &b[1], &b[2]);

   
    score = compareTriplets(a,b);
    
    for(k=0;k<2;k++)
    {
        printf("%d",score[k]);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: the best way: `printf("%d &d",score[0], score[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*compareTriplets* delivers a *pointer* to a int array.
Your score variable in your main method will therefore have to have the type `int *`. Meaning it is the pointer to the first int in the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int a[3];
int b[3];

int score[] = {0,0};

int *compareTriplets(int a[], int b[]);

int *compareTriplets(int a[], int b[])
{
    int i;
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if( a[i] > b[i])
        {
            score[0] += 1;
        }
        else if( b[i] > a[i])
        {
            score[1] += 1;
        }
    }

    return score;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    a[0] = a[1] = a[2] = 1;
    b[0] = b[1] = b[2] = 2;
    int *score = compareTriplets(a,b);
    printf("%d, %d\n", score[0], score[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

To print it, we access the array elements by the `[]` operator.

However let me add, that having your score array be a global variable seems like the wrong decision here.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful. and the score global variable, at first I declared it as a local variable in compareTriplet(), im just confuse. 

do i really need this parameter in the main function? `int argc, char** argv`
Thank you again!

Comment: No you don't necessarily need those two parameters in the main function, I just wrote them in there out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *compareTriplets(const int a[], const int b[], int *score)
{
    int i;
    
    score[0] = 0; score[1] = 0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if( a[i] > b[i])
        {
            score[0] += 1;
        }
        else if( b[i] > a[i])
        {
            score[1] += 1;
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Usage:

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[3] = {rand(), rand(), rand()};
    int b[3] = {rand(), rand(), rand()};
    int score[2];

    compareTriplets(a,b,score);
    printf("%d %d\n", score[0], score[1]);
}
```

or

```
struct score
{
    int score[2];
};

struct score compareTriplets(const int a[], const int b[])
{
    int i;
    struct score sc = {0,0};
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if( a[i] > b[i])
        {
            sc.score[0] += 1;
        }
        else if( b[i] > a[i])
        {
            sc.score[1] += 1;
        }
    }

    return sc;
}
```

and usage"

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[3] = {rand(), rand(), rand()};
    int b[3] = {rand(), rand(), rand()};
    struct score sc = compareTriplets(a,b);

    printf("%d %d\n", sc.score[0], sc.score[1]);
}
```